# How to maintain 6months history data?

Tags: sql, oracle10g

I am very new to DBA concepts. As part of work I have created a internal data mart. With the use of database links i have connected to different sources and what ever data is requested that information is stored in this mart. we have requirement that the data source i am connecting through database link is changes day by day. so we want to keep track of those changes in that data. so i have created a materialized view and write a procedure to refresh those tables once in a month. Means the main table is always refreshed with new data once in a month and we will send the old data to history tables.so before refreshing those tables, i have wrote a simple logic to move the data from main tables to history tables.
example:
Assume that employee table as a main table , to maintain history for that table i am writting a simple statement like

`create table employee_hst as select * from employee;`(with timestamp)

but that simple statement is not serving my purpose.

Because my requirement is that i should maintain history for only 6months. I mean history table  should hold only 6months history data. So please help me by telling how to store only 6months old data in hist data and more than 6months data should remove automatically.

Please please help with your suggestions.

Thanks in advance

Comment: This sounds like a perfect candidate for partitioning.  Do you have the partitioning option licensed?

Answer (score 1):

This is a simplified version of what you may need based on scott.emp table. First is to show you the query and the output. You may also use INTERVAL or ADD_MONTHS to get data for the last 6 months:

```
SELECT * FROM
(
 SELECT deptno, empno, ename, end_date AS hiredate
      , TRUNC(MONTHS_BETWEEN(sysdate, end_date)) months_of_service  
  FROM emp_test
)
WHERE months_of_service <= 6 -- past 6 moths data only
ORDER BY 1
/

DEPTNO    EMPNO    ENAME     HIREDATE    MONTHS_OF_SERVICE
------------------------------------------------------------
10        7782     CLARK     11/2/2012    4
10        7934     MILLER    9/2/2012     6
...
20        7902     FORD      9/2/2012     6
20        7566     JONES     10/2/2012    5
...
30        7935     WALSH     12/2/2012    3
30        7900     JAMES     9/2/2012     6
30        7844     TURNER    1/27/2013    1
...
```

Below example is based on your post - you want to recreate table every time and populate it with data. You may also truncate table and reinsert the data - up to you. I personally would choose truncate/insert instead of dropping/creating tables dynamically.

Create procedure with table name as parameter, or run block manually, or schedule it with DBMS_SCHEDULER or some other tool to run automatically every time interval you pass to SCHEDULER.

Add schema name before table name. Remove the exception part from the code if table already exists before running below Drop table part. If you get "ORA-00942: table or view does not exist" then you need an exception.

```
DECLARE
  v_tab_name VARCHAR2(100):= 'emp_test2';
BEGIN
  EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'DROP TABLE '|| v_tab_name; -- may truncate then insert 
  -- This exception will handle ORA-00942: table or view does not exist
  -- If table already exists before you run this then you may remove it from code
  EXCEPTION WHEN OTHERS 
  THEN
    BEGIN
      EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'CREATE TABLE '||v_tab_name||' AS -- or insert into select...
                  SELECT * FROM
                   (
                   SELECT deptno, empno, ename, end_date
                        , TRUNC(MONTHS_BETWEEN(sysdate, end_date)) months_of_service  
                     FROM emp_test
                   )
                   WHERE months_of_service <= 6
                  ORDER BY 1'; 

       EXCEPTION WHEN OTHERS THEN dbms_output.put_line(SQLCODE||' '||SQLERRM); 
    END;
 END;
/
```

Answer (score 0):

You could create a stored procedure that

1. inserts into history
2. Refreshes the materilaised View
3. Deletes from History `where DateCreated < Sysdate - 180`

Comment: Deleting from a table in a 'insert into history' sp would be highly counterintuitive.  Especially as first-run performance would be non-deterministic.

Comment: Think of what your SP would be named; is it `insertIntoHistory`?  If so, why would it delete anything?  Is it named `insertAndDeleteFromHistory`?  If so, does that mean the row just inserted is also being deleted (or is related to the deleted rows)?  Really, inserting the row is a completely different need than the deletion: rows are being deleted due to size or a fulfilled legal requirement (or whatever).  ... Also, I have a feeling refreshing the materialized view after every insert is going to be a performance hog (and _before_ the delete?).

Comment: You could call it `MaintainHistory`.  The idea would be to add new history records and trim old ones.

Answer (score 0):

Can you create a trigger on the employee table that will execute on INSERT/UPDATE/DELETE, which would do two things: 1) copy the current record  in the history table. The history table would have a separate field as a varchar[20] or something similar that would hold the action "INSERT/UPDATE/DELETE" as well as a timestamp field. The second action that it would do is to delete any records in the history table older than 180 days.

Comment: Actually, deleting records from history inside an 'add to history' trigger would be rather counterintuitive.  Especially from a performance standpoint.

Answer (score 0):

Almost all RDBMSs have some sort of scheduling service intact, including [Oracle](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/appdev.102/b14258/d_sched.htm).

Your best bet is to add a scheduled job to this service, that removes all history older than 6 months (or 180 days or what have you).